# Why does carousel item in bootstrap use perspective 1000?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been customizing bootstrap  carousel and I noticed the following code:

```
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform .6s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
```

First there are no 3d effects in bootstrap carousel so there is no need of this. Secondly suppose we want to customize the carousel so that the slides have 3d effects then this would be necessary. But! perspective is used upon the parent element not on the one which is going to have 3d effects. In my custmization I noticed that for `.items` to have 3d effects I need

```
.carousel-inner {
  perspective: 1000;
}
```

So the question:

- Why does carousel item in bootstrap use perspective 1000?

Answer (score 1):

> The use of translate3d pushes CSS animations into hardware acceleration. Even if you're looking to do a basic 2d translation, use translate3d for more power! If your animation is still flickering after switching to the transform above, you can use a few little-known CSS properties to try to fix the problem:

```
.animClass {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

Source: [Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit with translate3d](https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d)

I think this is the reason, to force hardware acceleration (GPU) for smoother transitions in certain browsers.

Comment: If adding translate3d already takes gpu in action then why perspective property too is used? Does using more 3d properties causes more gpu involvement?

Comment: It's difficult to say, I can't find anything on the web which explains it precisely.